# What does "до" and "со значительными утратами" mean in this sentence?

Tags: предлоги, idioms

At the Russian wiki page for the ["All Saint's Bridge"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82), it says:

> Представлял собой выдающееся архитектурное и инженерное сооружение, считался одним из чудес Москвы. Существовал, со значительными утратами, до 1853 года .

Google Translate gives the last sentence as "There, with considerable losses, up to 1853."

But what does that mean? Does it mean the bridge was destroyed in 1853? If so, I don't understand what the "со значительными утратами" is trying to say either.

Comment: it could be understood as that major parts of the bridge original structure were destroyed or lost, this seems to be a phrase from professional jargon of art historians, which is revealed by Google search for `"со значительными утратами"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the bridge existed until 1853, although it had lost some major parts (probably it was damaged, or simply decayed) even before that.

[This site](http://www.openmoscow.ru/mostbolkamenny.php) claims that the bridge was intentionally destroyed in 1859 due to its bad condition.

Answer (score 0):

'со значительными утратами, до': 'with substantial damage, up to'